# Assign value only if not nil

Tags: ruby

I can replace this:

```
le_one = load_le_other() unless le_one
```

with this:

```
le_one ||= load_le_other()
```

How can I replace this:

```
le_other = load_le_other()
le_one = le_other if le_other
```

with something other than this:

```
le_other = load_le_other()
le_one = le_other || le_one
```

`load_le_other` is expensive to call twice. The goal is to make it one liner.

Comment: I don't see where `load_le_other` is called twice.

Comment: I find it curious that so many readers interpreted "`load_le_other` is expensive to call twice" to mean that the OP's code called that method  twice and that was to be avoided. Does it not make more sense to interpret it as meaning the one-liner should not call that method twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace with this:

```
le_one = load_le_other() || le_one
```

Comment: That is what the OP explicitly claimed they want to avoid.

Comment: @sawa well, may be, will wait lucas

Comment: It's a one-liner that calls `load_le_other()` only once. If that's not exactly what's being asked, then the question needs to be edited.

Comment: Values are to be assigned to both `le_one` and `le_other`. The OP did not say that `le_other` was needed only for determining the value of `le_one`.

Answer (score 0):

If `load_le_other()` cannot return `false`,

```
le_one = le_other = load_le_other()
```

Note that if

```
le_other = load_le_other()
  #=> nil
le_one = le_other if le_other
  # le_one = nil if nil
  #=> nil
```

Answer (score 0):

This will assign the appropriate values to both `le_one` and `le_other`:

```
le_one = (le_other = le_load_other()).nil? ? le_one : le_other
```

It's counterintuitive that you could assign `le_one` to itself before you've even defined it, but it works.

If you have already defined `le_one` you can also do this:

```
le_other = le_load_other()&.tap { |val| le_one = val }
```

The `&.` causes the tap (and its block) to only execute if le_load_other() returns a non-nil value.